# Remove square brackets and inverted commas from view, rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, view

I have an each statement in a view:

```
<tr><% @quantity.each do |hash| %>
<td><%= hash.map { |key, value| "Channel: #{key} Quantity: #{value} units" } %>
</td><% end %></tr>
```

which is rendering on the webpage with square brackets and inverted commas, thus:

["Channel: 1 Quantity: 4675 units"]

["Channel: 2 Quantity: 2864 units"]

The array of hashes that it's looping round is this:

```
[{2=>2864}, {1=>4675}]
```

How do I stop the [" from showing up on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: wfm. What version of ruby/rails you using?

Comment: Interesting: I'm on Rails 3.0.6, Ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` maps a hash into an array. The output is what it should be. Instead of using `map`, try:

```
@quantity.each do |hash|
    hash.inspect
end
```

Should help.

**Edit** in response to your comment:

```
@quantity.each do |hash|
    hash.each do |key, value|
        "Key: #{key} Value: #{value}"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @sorrow. That gives me {2=>2864} {1=>4675}. Ideally I'd want to see something like Channel: 2, 2864 units.

Comment: Huge thanks for the edit. It's helped me understand a lot more of the fundamentals, too. I was being a bit thick.

Comment: Glad to help. For learning Ruby I recommend a free book [Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby). For Rails there are more than enough guides online.